# HTML flex box layout - scrolled element won't stretch

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout that looks something like this:

[image]

Where the header and footer are pinned to the window and the blue area scrolls vertically if it needs space.

I thought `display:flex` would do it, and the code below gets close, but there is a problem. If you scroll that content area, it looks like this:

[image]

It appears that the divs for the "left nav" and "content" are chopped to the height of the their parent, even though that parent is scrollable.

```js
var linesToAdd = 100;
var html = "";
for (var i=0; i<linesToAdd; i++) {
   html += i + "<br/>"
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%
}
#header, #footer {
  background: #ffa0a0;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
#mid {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #a08080;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
}
#leftnav {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #8a8;
}
#content {
  background: #88a;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
       
  <div id='mid'>
    <div id='leftnav'>Left nav</div>
    <div id='content'></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I can modify that slightly to make it work when the content is overflowing, but then it doesn't work when the content is smaller.  I'm looking for something that stretches vertically to the footer, when content is small, but overflows without chopping the backgrounds when content is large.

```js
// With 100 here it looks good, but with 5, you see it doesn't stretch vertically.
var linesToAdd = 5;
var html = "";
for (var i=0; i<linesToAdd; i++) {
   html += i + "<br/>"
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%
}
#header, #footer {
  background: #ffa0a0;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
#mid {
  flex-grow:1;
  background:#a88;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#leftnav {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #8a8;
}
#content {
  background: #88a;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
       
  <div id='mid' style="">
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div id='leftnav'>Left nav</div>      
      <div id='content'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nawxq4s5/2/) maybe??

Comment: Change that 100 to 10 and you'll see why not. It won't stretch to fill.

Comment: You mean the `100vh`? Why would you change it to 10? Your code was almost right you just needed to make the `body` 100% of the viewport in order for it to work and that's exactly what `100vh` does. I might be confused?

Comment: My bad. I meant the 100 in the JS loop.  I want the elements to stretch to fill available space.  If you only produce 10 lines, it shows how they do not stretch vertically to fill.

Comment: oh ok that makes more sense

Comment: Ok how about this [one](https://jsfiddle.net/nawxq4s5/3/). It does require to define a height for your header and footer though

Comment: Thanks, that works, but like you said requiring a height on header/footer is not ideal. I may just to do that.

Comment: Yea I don't like setting static heights (even though `vh` is a relative height) on my elements, but I have found in practice that headers and footers _usually_ don't have dynamic content so it's ok to set heights on them when you need to calculate the height of the main content area

Answer (score 1):

**You need to set `height` on HTML too.**

The [faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) method can help you here: 
(*method revisited with gradient, but multiple backgrounds would work too* )

```html
<html>
<style>
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .headorfoot {
    background: #ffa0a0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
</style>

<body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100%">

  <div class="headorfoot">
    Header
  </div>

  <div id='mid' style="flex-grow:1;background:linear-gradient(to right,#80A080 200px,gray 200px , gray 203px, #8080A0 203px);;overflow-y:scroll;  display:flex">
    <!-- <div style="display:flex"> -->
    <div style="padding: 10px;width:200px;">Left nav</div>
    <div style="width:3px;"></div>
    <div style="padding: 10px;background:#8080a0;flex:1">
      <script>
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          document.write(i + "<br/>");
        }
      </script>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->
  </div>
  <div class="headorfoot">
    Footer
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

You may also want to use : `position:sticky` for the left nav, (polyfills exists if you think it useful )

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}
.headorfoot {
  background: #ffa0a0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#mid {
  background: #8080a0;;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.scroll {
  flex:1;
  border-left:solid gray;
  
}
.nav {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

/* demo purpose */
.scroll:hover br {
  float:left;
  display:none;/* where float doesn't work ... demo purpose only */
}
```

```html
<div class="headorfoot">
  Header
</div>

<div id='mid'>

  <div class="nav" style="padding: 10px;background:#80a080">Left nav</div>
  <div class="scroll" style="padding: 10px;background:#8080a0;">
    <script>
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        document.write(i + "<br/>");
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="headorfoot">
  Footer
</div>
```

Comment: I click "run code snippet" and it shows the exact same problem. You scroll and the green and blue are chopped off.

Comment: @RobN the green/ blue is chopped off cause it is .mid scrolling not the container wich overflows mid ... nothing strange here, don' set any background on it let show mid bg through it. you can inspire yourself from the faux-column method  http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns if you need left nav to scroll too

Comment: @RobN i updated answer with the faux-clumn method while waiting feed back check it. good day i'll be gone next few hours

Comment: Actually it is strange. Here's the normal behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/ztc3x58w/  See how when you scroll the container you see the full inner div, including it's background.

Comment: @RobN normal behavior indeed, but container isn't flex, so childs expands as normal ;)  as a flex chid that's how it goes https://jsfiddle.net/m9fd943x/ and then make it expand to the whole flex container https://jsfiddle.net/m9fd943x/1/ content overflows and only the container scrolls

Comment: Do you know if the flexbox spec says to behave like this? Hard for me to believe they would design it like that on purpose.

Comment: by defaut childs fill ups width & height  of flex container if an height is set to flex-container, else flex container grows as tall as child is.(row-direction, column direction turns to be opposite. as soon as you set size to prent or childs behavior follows. container sized might show a scroll bar but won't expand as a table would. More information can be found on W3C  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/  https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102284/discussion-between-rob-n-and-gcyrillus).